# Advice for troubleshooting assembly load problems/file not found exceptions on Azure app service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-assembly

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to troubleshoot .NET assembly load issues on Azure app service (Azure webjobs). My challenge is I have significantly less visibility (I think?) on Azure than locally, because, for example I can't use the Fusion Log viewer to get assembly binding information.

My specific problem relates to the Amazon Web Services AWS Polly Nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Polly/3.3.103.52.

Per the message below, the AWSSDK.Polly v3.3 dll with public key token 885c28607f98e604 cannot be found.  *Note: This only happens on Azure; it loads fine in my local development environment.*

- The DLL is in the project bin directory in development environment and is in the webjob executable directory
- I have confirmed using the sn.exe tool (part of Visual Studio) via `sn -Tp AWSSDK.Polly.dll` that the public key token shown in the error log is the same public key token shown in the sn.exe command output.

I was exploring possible binding redirect issues and (a) have no binding redirect statements in my `.config` file (should I?) and (b) didn't think binding redirects were required unless there were some dependency conflict which I currently have no evidence of.

What are recommendations for troubleshooting this?

> Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Polly, Version=3.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified. File name: 'AWSSDK.Polly, Version=3.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule
>   pModule, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob,
>   Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module,
>   RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr
>   blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder1&
>   attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32
>   decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean
>   mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder1 derivedAttributes)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Type type,
>   Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](MemberInfo
>   element, Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.TryResolveStateMachineMethod(MethodBase&
>   method, Type& declaringType)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)    at
>   System.Exception.get_StackTrace()    at
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException.ToString()    at
>   MyApp.Processors.VProcessor.ProcessQueueMessageAsync(queueItem
>   item)

Answer (score 0):

Here a couple of points to check from your local machine

1. Delete `bin`, `obj` & `packages` directories in your local machine.
2. Then try to use `nuget restore`. This has to install the AWS nuget package.
3. In the project file (.csproj), search for the dll and find from where is it referenced, if it is referenced from packages directory, it is fine. if it is referenced from `bin` directory by mistake that should cause the reference to fail.
4. Build the project, see if the references are still intact and the dll reference issue is resolved
5. If you are using a version of .net that is different from the hosting environment, this issue can occur. Some nuget packages work with a specific target .net version and if the hosting environment doesn't have that version, there may be this error
6. Try to get hold of the deployed package and inspect it to see if the references are fine
7. Try to host the package (6) in you IIS to see if you are getting similar error

Please share your findings after trying out the above options